# Vision range around my position in google maps

Tags: android, mobile, google-maps-mobile

I want to create a vision range around my position in google maps. I know I have to write a subclass of MyLocationOverlay, and rotate triangle image in drawCompass method, but does anyone have a example of it, because I cant rotate image in right way.

![e
nter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQvRO.png)